# List is no longer defined after For While loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was working on a script and I wanted to get rid of a nested list that was created when data was sorted from a text file. After the nested list was removed and placed in a "cleaned" list, I wanted to sort through that list and remove unwanted information. My problem appeared when trying to print the list. When typing print before my for loop, it prints properly. After, I get an error stating that the list is not defined when it is clearly defined at the top and referenced earlier in the program.

This is the error I get when print is after the for loop:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DIRECTORY OF PROGRAM.py", line 64, in <module>
    print(clnwrd)
NameError: name 'clnwrd' is not defined
```

And here is my code:

```
import os
import sys

words = []
clnwrd = []


# checks for apostrophes
def apostro(value):
    if value == '\'':
        return True

    else:
        return False


# removes nesting lists
def nonest(x, newlist):
    for y in x:
        for z in y:
             newlist.append(str(z))

    return newlist        
            
# opens file
with open('Path to specified file', 'r') as data:

    for line in data:
        word = ""
        
        for character in line:
            # skips apostrophes
            if character == '\'':
                pass

            else:
                # adds words to the list
                word += str(character)

        # splits words by selected character
        if "THINg" in word:
            words.append(word.split("THING"))

            if "THING" in word:
                words.append(word.split("THING"))

        else:
            words.append(word.split("Key."))


nonest(words, clnwrd)


print(clnwrd) # THE PRINT STATEMENT WORKS HERE

for thing in clnwrd:
    if "THING" in thing:
        del clnwrd
    
    if "THING" in thing:
        thing.split("THING")

    if "THING" in thing:
        thing.split("THING")


# IF print(clnwrd) IS PLACED RIGHT HERE it DOESN'T WORK
```

And before anyone asks, yes I checked the identation and made sure the print statement was outside the for loop. Any help is appreaciated.

Comment: If `"THING"` is in `thing`, you `del clnwrd` - it's pretty much gone after that, so I would presume `"THING"` was in `thing`?

Comment: You delete it and then ask us why it isn't found? And I also see `str.split` calls by themselves without saving the result, too. I'd say you should take another look at whatever instructional material you're using.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think `del clnwrd` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in a single line of your code:

```
del clnwrd
```

I think you may have meant:

```
def clnwrd[index of value]
```

The following code worked for me:
**Full Code:**

```
import os
import sys

words = []
clnwrd = []


# checks for apostrophes
def apostro(value):
    if value == '\'':
        return True

    else:
        return False


# removes nesting lists
def nonest(x, newlist):
    for y in x:
        for z in y:
            newlist.append(str(z))

    return newlist


# opens file
with open('Path to specified file', 'r') as data:
    for line in data:
        word = ""

        for character in line:
            # skips apostrophes
            if character == '\'':
                pass

            else:
                # adds words to the list
                word += str(character)

        # splits words by selected character
        if "THINg" in word:
            words.append(word.split("THING"))

            if "THING" in word:
                words.append(word.split("THING"))

        else:
            words.append(word.split("Key."))

nonest(words, clnwrd)

print(clnwrd)  # THE PRINT STATEMENT WORKS HERE
idx = 0
for thing in clnwrd:
    if "THING" in thing:
        del clnwrd[idx]

    if "THING" in thing:
        thing.split("THING")

    if "THING" in thing:
        thing.split("THING")
    idx += 1

print(clnwrd) # PRINT STATEMENT WORKS HERE AS WELL
```

**Explanation:**

`del` is used to remove the whole list, if index is not specified:
To learn more about `del` in Python, visit:

> https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_del.asp

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot. I was staring at it for hours thinking it deletes the specified index instead of the whole list. Thank you!